# Local wifi network community bulletin board

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, captive-portal

I'm trying to make an online community bulletin board for the people in my apartment building. Here's what I'm envisioning: I'll set up a wifi network, "Bulletin Board", and when people connect to my network their browsers will redirect to my bulletin board site. It's like a tiny version of the internet that contains only my site. I'm not really sure how to proceed, does any body know any good places to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to is called a 'captive portal' -- a good place to start might be here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal

Comment: If in fact you decide you don't want to be the gateway, and just host a site, you could use MAMP for mac, XAMPP or WAMP or IIS for windows, linux has many server methods.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jeff's answer, while it doesn't look exactly like a captive portal, the fundamentals are the same - you will intercept other people's connections.

They won't like it, since their connections would be redirected without their consent; it's a privacy and security problem - since you'd access their cookies, HTTP requests and whatnot - and in a technical level, you would face problems such as HTTPS connections failing with invalid certificates.

If you are attempting to do BBS systems as they were in the 80s, you're better off just making your own website and leaving it publicly accessible. Try to use your wireless networking resources to provide access to the Internet to more people in your community, instead of closing them in your website only :)

Comment: Yep, it all depends if you want to be a gateway as well, or just a web host. I think there would have to be a good reason, there would have to be a really good board, or a higher speed connection for them to want to go through your portal.

Comment: Correct Valmiky, it was also however the closest thing I have seen to what was being asked, that has options already available for the purpose.

Comment: Yes, it does look like the best place to start, I'm not denying that.

I don't get where these downvotes come from, though. It's a legitimate question, and I don't see anything wrong with the answers. I upvoted the question and your answer just to get them to zero.

Comment: I agree, downvotes without any reason given are kind of silly, and why downvote anyone for trying to help out someone attempting to accomplish a technical goal? Beyond me... [I upvoted you as well, and thanks for that]

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I'm not sure why we got downvoted. I'm not using it as a gateway, just a fun way to interact with my neighbors and learn about networking -- probably no one will use it. I'm going to give captive portal a try.

Comment: I would love to see you post your results after, I have set up wireless for coffee shops and small businesses like many people here, and I can say this - if you find a way that works well for you - maybe you can sell your services to businesses as well. Just a thought. *That of course would be the perfect reason for a captive portal*